# Which AMD Graphics card should I install the driver for on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have two AMD Graphics Cards on my system.

I am quite sure that the Radeon HD 7640G works better than Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series.

I would just like to use only the 7640G and install proprietary driver from AMD site for the same.

A screenshot to about my System Info has also been provided below.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank You

lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G] [1002:9903]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840]

[System Information Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx7YM.png)

Comment: You don't need to install anything. Thee are no proprietary drivers available.

Answer (score 0):

Depends: If you have an HD 7500M, the [HD 7640M is 4% faster](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/AMD-Radeon-HD-7640G-vs-AMD-Radeon-HD-7500M/m7903vsm8602); if you have an HD 7600M, it's [21% faster than the HD 7640M](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/AMD-Radeon-HD-7640G-vs-AMD-Radeon-HD-7600M/m7903vsm9552).